# Special characters in data attribute values

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an html content where this can be found:

```
<li data-id="87dhqsiu37fGyqUNA786d6F7=">
```

*Note the `=` sign at the end of the data attribute value*

How can I select it using a jQuery selector?

I tried this without success:

```
$("li [data-id=87dhqsiu37fGyqUNA786d6F7]")
$("li [data-id=87dhqsiu37fGyqUNA786d6F7\=]")
$("li [data-id=87dhqsiu37fGyqUNA786d6F7\u003D]")
$("li [data-id=87dhqsiu37fGyqUNA786d6F7&#61;]")
```

Each time gets me a Syntax Error (except for the first line, which just doesn't find the element).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to css selector `$("li [data-id=87dhqsiu37fGyqUNA786d6F7]")` means any element with `data-id` attribute but in children of `<li>`.

But here `<li>` itselt is a element with `data-id` attribute.

So the correct syntax is

```
$('li[data-id="87dhqsiu37fGyqUNA786d6F7="]')
```

Just a simple issue of CSS selector syntax.

Answer (score 4):

`li [data-id=...]` implies "any element with `data-id` of `...`, which is a descendant of any `<li>` element"

What you want is `li[data-id=...]` which means "any `<li>` element with `data-id` attribute with value of `...`".

This is not a problem with any specific library, that's how CSS selectors work.